# What does this do: fps = scene.render.fps / scene.render.fps_base?

Tags: python

In blender python what does `fps = scene.render.fps / scene.render.fps_base` exactly do? I understand that it gives frames per second but how does that work. What is `scene.render.fps_blender`?

Answer (score 2):

In command

`fps = scene.render.fps / scene.render.fps_base`

`fps` is a variable that is given the value of the actual framerate of the scene.

`scene.render.fps` is the framerate but can only hold integer values. If you want non-integer framerates this value has to be divided by some value. Default is 24.

`scene.render.fps_base` is a way to get non-integer framerates. The type is a Float and the default is 1.0.

`scene.render.fps_blender` doesn't exist and will give you an error.

Examples:

1. 60.0 = 60/1.0
2. 20.5 = 41/2.0
3. 29.75 = 30/1.008